# Return String after the last Symbol

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle I have a column in one of our tables that shows the file pathway of a given report. However I just need the name of the report to come back to use to connect to another table.

The column can be a string as follows:

```
Report_Name
-----------
Public >> Reports >> Division1 >> Customer Service >> ReportABC
Public >> Reports >> Division2 >> Purchasing >> Details >> ReportXYZ
Public >> Reports >> Division1 >> Purchasing >> Details >> Report Last Year
```

I always need the information following the last ">>"

So the returned values would look something like:

```
Report_Name
-----------
ReportABC
ReportXYZ
Report Last Year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `>` is only used as a separator, you can do:

```
select trim(regexp_substr(Report_Name, '[^>]*$')) as Report_Name
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Regex always stumps me.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Regular Expression with Sub-expression  or Non-Regular Expression**

With the non-regular expression solution, I just use the instr function to find the first `>` (starting from right side of the string) and add 1 to the position. This value is passed to the substr function as the starting positional value.  Like Gordon, I just use trim function to clean-up spaces to the left afterwards.

With the regular expression, I just use overloaded version of the regexp_substr which takes a sub-expression and I make the report name associated to the sub-expression by placing this in parenthesis.

```
 SCOTT@db>WITH smple AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          'Public >> Reports >> Division1 >> Customer Service >> ReportABC' pth
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT
  8          'Customer Service >> ReportABC' pth
  9      FROM
 10          dual
 11  ) SELECT
 12      pth,
 13      TRIM(substr(pth, (instr(pth,'>',-1) ) + 1) ) rprt_name,
 14      regexp_substr(pth,'>>\s*([^>]*)$',1,1,NULL,1) rprt_name2
 15    FROM
 16      smple;

PTH                                                               RPRT_NAME   RPRT_NAME2   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public >> Reports >> Division1 >> Customer Service >> ReportABC   ReportABC   ReportABC    
Customer Service >> ReportABC                                     ReportABC   ReportABC
```